# What happens if I pay for changing my character appearance but end up canceling the editing?

Tags: pc, ps4, xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

On the New Generation versions of Grand Theft Auto Online, you can pay GTA$100.000 for editing your character appearance from the interaction menu.

What happens if I go back to the game without doing any changes? Is my money refunded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The money is taken after you make the character changes. If you don't make any changes, no money will be charged.

So, I picked up the "Change Appearance" option from the interaction to see what would happen:

[image]

That threw me into the character editor:

[image]

On that screen, I just pressed circle to go back into the game and it told me that no charge was made:

[image]

After confirming that, the game sent me into the Single Player mode. After going back to GTA Online, I checked if my GTA$100.000 were still there and they were:

[image]